# Debian+Apache+Traccar setup

Tags: java, apache, ip, debian

I am planning to get `VPS` for a website and Traccar app (https://www.traccar.org). I don't have a lot of experience with setting up this kind of solution, so I want to ask first. I have no problem with installing Apache, setting up the website and install the app, but here is the thing. On the website **www.xyz.com** there is a **log in** button which will direct to the app interface, which I like to be on **app.xyz.com**. I can setup the app to be accessible on a different port then 80. How do you setup the server? vHost with different ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache proxy module to run Traccar as a virtual host.

Configuration should look something like this (not tested):

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/
    ServerName app.xyz.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will try that and will let you know, if it works.

Comment: Now I get the same result on www.xyz.com and app.xyz.com, which means that I see the website on both domains. If I add :8082 on either of them, it access Traccar. Am I doing something wrong?